# yii2 - How to get checked checkbox values from gridview to controller

Tags: php, yii2

I need to get checked checkbox value from my view to controller when button is press.

Gridview :

```
<div class="installment-ready">
<!-- <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1> -->
<?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
    [
    'class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
    'contentOptions'=>[ 'style'=>'width: 60px'],
    ],
//Checkbox
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
    'contentOptions'=>[ 'style'=>'width: 50px'],
    'name' => 'checked',
    'checkboxOptions'=> function($model, $key, $index, $column) {
     return ["value" => $model->ACCOUNT_ID];
    }
],
```

Button to process selected checkbox:

```
<?= Html::a('Submit', ['#'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success pull-right']) ?>
```

Comment: update question with info of `Yii::$app->request->post()`.

Comment: I already try to post the data, but it not show in controller. This is one of the checkbox '<input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="45678">'. I think the checkbox itself not contain my value

Comment: hum, have you try in your controller ->  var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post()); ? The button submit a form?

Comment: when I var_dump, the data not post to my controller. array(0) { }

Comment: To test it you use jquery. when click on the submit button you can test if your checkbox are checked and relative value. I don't know your code, but i think you doesn't pass your value via POST method to the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I'm using ajax to post selected checkbox to my controller.

Script that I use in my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // action for all selected rows
  function submit(){
    var dialog = confirm("Are you sure to submit the installment?");
    if (dialog == true) {
        var keys = $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
        // console.log(keys);
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'index.php?r=installment/submit', // Your controller action
            data: {keylist: keys},
            success: function(result){
              console.log(result);
            }
          });
    }
  }
</script>
<!-- Submit button -->
<button type="button" onclick="submit()" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button
```

And you can use usual Yii::$app->request->post() in controller to get your data.

Comment: I have tried your way but still unable to get the posted data can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56196185/unable-to-post-the-data-from-view-to-controller-in-yii2)?

Answer (score 1):

In your `controller` action use below code

```
Yii::$app->request->post('checked');
```

Comment: I already try to post the data, but it not show in controller. This is one of the checkbox <input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="45678">. I think the checkbox itself not contain my value.